# The element's value is different from that appended to the list

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is a section of my code. When i execute the program the output i get is included beneath the code.

```
    currentPos = playerPosition
    modifiedCords = freespaceCords
    pathList = []
    while(True):
        adjacentList = []
        potentialMoveList = []

        currentPos[0] = currentPos[0] - 1
        adjacentList.append(currentPos)
        print(currentPos)

        currentPos[0] = currentPos[0] + 2
        adjacentList.append(currentPos)
        print(currentPos)

        currentPos[0] = currentPos[0] - 1
        currentPos[1] = currentPos[1] - 1
        adjacentList.append(currentPos)
        print(currentPos)

        currentPos[1] = currentPos[1] + 2
        adjacentList.append(currentPos)
        print(currentPos)
        currentPos[1] = currentPos[1] - 1

        print("")
        print(adjacentList)
        print("")
```

output:

```
[0, 1]

[2, 1]

[1, 0]

[1, 2]


[[1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1]]
```

I would like the list of 4 elements to contain the previous four individually printed elements such that:

```
[ [0,1] , [2,1] , [1,0] , [1,2] ]
```

Please could someone provide a solution to my problem, explain why their solution works and why my code does not.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

```
adjacentList.append(currentPos)
```

You are appending a reference to the list `currentPos` to `adjacentList`. So each time you change `currentPos` you are actually changing the elements in `adjacentList` as well. If you print `adjacentList` in your intermediate steps, you will see what I mean.

To circumvent this, you can append a copy of your list instead:

```
adjacentList.append(list(currentPos))
```

Here is an example where you can see what I described:

```
>>> l = [1, 1]
>>> adjacentList = []
>>> adjacentList.append(l)
>>> adjacentList
[[1, 1]]
>>> l[1] = 2
>>> adjacentList
[[1, 2]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are adding references not a copy of the list.
To show that we may use built-in `id` function

add the following code to the end of your loop

```
print(id(adjacentList[0])
print(id(adjacentList[1])
print(id(adjacentList[2])
print(id(adjacentList[3])
print(id(currentPos))
```

you will find that four elements inside `adjacentList` and `currentPos` have the same id which is exactly the same object inside memory.

Instead of have to append a copy of the `currentPos` not a reference using one of the many  methods ( I will only mention one and the others can be checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list)

```
# Since Python 3.3
adjacentList.append(currentPos.copy())
```

Answer (score 0):

When you `.append(currentPosition)` to your list, you are adding the same actual object 4 times. Since you have that object in 4 positions, if you change it, all the positions will change. The simplest way would be to store a copy of the object, which you can do by just adding `.append(list(currentPosition))`, or `.append(currentPosition[:])`.

Answer (score 0):

Your question has already been answered by others. Anyway I would like to add to the above answers by means of a very simple example that can help you understand better.

Executing the below code,

```
input = [1,2]
output = []

output.append(input)
print("output list after appending %s"%output)

input[0] = 4
output.append(input)
print("output list after appending again %s"%output)
```

you get the following output

```
output list after appending [[1, 2]]
output list after appending again [[4, 2], [4, 2]]
```

It can be seen that after the second append, even output[0] gets re.written. This is because output[0] has a reference to input[] and when the input list was modified, even output[0] gets the latest value.

On the other hand, if you do the following,

```
input = [1,2]
output = []

output.append(input.copy())
print("output list after appending %s"%output)

input[0] = 4
output.append(input.copy())
print("output list after appending again %s"%output)
```

You get the expected output

```
output list after appending [[1, 2]]
output list after appending again [[1, 2], [4, 2]]
```

Now output[0] is not overwritten because a copy of input[] is made and not a reference.